# Laravel 8.0.9 Heroku Deployment Failed to install system packages

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, composer-php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvRK9.png)

try to push my app to heroku but keep showing this problem

im sure my composer is 2.2.3, tried `composer self-update -1` to rollback to composer 1 then update to composer 2, but still wont work.

tired with  `composer require composer-plugin-api` still the same

here is my composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "composer-plugin-api": "^2.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "overtrue/laravel-lang": "~4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you need `composer-plugin-api`? If not, you can remove it.

Comment: The current Composer plugin API version is 2.1.0 (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md). You're trying to use a version (2.2 or higher) that does not exist yet.

Comment: What is "this problem"? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó how do i check my current composer plugin API version? thanks

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is in the image , i try to push my app to heroku but it keep telling me im using composer 1, then i go to upgrade my composer it still not working.

Comment: after i close all my cmd and homestead, then run composer update, it fixed... idk why but i can push my app to heroku now.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the error message in text form. Also, is there anything not working with your code if you removed the line requiring `composer-plugin-api`?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I think that this is a documentation issue - 2.2.0 is the current API version, see https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/2.2/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginInterface.php